# MEAN stack multiple image upload and edit with multer and mimeType

Tags: node.js, angular, file-upload, mean-stack, multer

Please help
I am using reactive form in angular and I cannot update uploaded images. With single image everything is ok, problem comes when I try to upload and edit multiple images, especially with editing.

Comment: Can you please help us with what you have tried till now. You can update your question with more details(current code)

Comment: Dear @SiddharthPal the code is too big, If You can, please create some sample with multiple image upload, mimeType, multer and edit